# Summing one particular column to n number of columns in every 2 and 3 possible combinations

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

I have a dataset of 240 columns and 146 rows. I am providing only first to chunks from the dataset with 5 rows

```
DF <- data.frame(
          D1 = c(-0.253, 0.253, -0.951, 0.951, 0.501, -0.501),
          D2 = c(-0.52, -0.52, 0.52, 0.52, -0.172, -0.172),
          D3 = c(0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, -0.014, -0.014),
          S3 = c(0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095),
          D1 = c(-0.966, 0.966, -0.647, 0.647, 0.905, -0.905),
          D2 = c(-0.078, -0.078, 0.078, 0.078, -0.943, -0.943),
          D3 = c(-0.046, -0.046, -0.046, -0.046, 0.046, 0.046),
          S3 = c(0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07)
)
```

I want to add every 4th column (i.e. S3) with the preceding 3 columns as the following combinations

```
D1+S3
D2+S3
D3+S3
D1+D2+S3
D1+D3+S3
```

Now in the new dataframe the columns should be
`D1 D2 D3 S3 D1+S3 D2+S3 D3+S3 D1+D2+S3 D1+D3+S3 D1 D2 D3 S3 D1+S3 D2+S3 D3+S3 D1+D2+S3 D1+D3+S3`

How to do it in R? Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Is there any logic in those combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code I reshape your data frame so that it brings all the values into 4 columns. To distinguish between the original columns, I have added an ID column. After that the operation you want to do becomes easy.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table(
"D1         D2     D3      S3      D1       D2      D3    S3
-0.253  -0.520  0.014   0.095   -0.966  -0.078  -0.046  0.070
0.253   -0.520  0.014   0.095   0.966   -0.078  -0.046  0.070
-0.951  0.520   0.014   0.095   -0.647  0.078   -0.046  0.070
0.951   0.520   0.014   0.095   0.647   0.078   -0.046  0.070
0.501   -0.172  -0.014  0.095   0.905   -0.943  0.046   0.070
-0.501  -0.172  -0.014  0.095   -0.905  -0.943  0.046   0.070
")

i <- seq(1, ncol(df)-3, 4)

df_out <- map_dfr(i, ~select(df, seq(., .+3)) %>% set_names(c("D1", "D2", "D3", "S3"))) 

df_out %>% 
  mutate(d1d2s3 = D1 + D2 + D3,
         d1d3s3 = D1 + D3 + D3,
         id = rep(1:length(i), each = nrow(df))) %>% 
  mutate_at(1:3, ~.+S3) %>% 
  bind_cols(df_out, .)
```

If you want to return it to the original shape after that you can do the following.

```r
df_out %>% 
  group_split(id) %>% 
  bind_cols()
```

**Edit:**
I have rewritten the code so as to work for a for a variable number of decompositions. You should just have to change `n_decomp <- 3` to the appropriate number. It creates variables for all possible combinations of the decomposition variables with S3. So it'll escalate quickly with an increasing number of decompositions.

```r
n_decomp <- 3
n_var <- n_decomp + 1
i <- seq(1, ncol(df), n_var)
df_names <- names(df[1:n_var])

df_out <- 
  map_dfr(i,
          ~select(df, seq(., .+n_decomp)) %>%
            set_names(df_names)) %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:length(i), each = nrow(df)))


decomp_combn <- map(1:n_decomp, 
    ~combn(df_names[1:n_decomp], .) %>% 
      as_tibble %>% 
      as.list) %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  map(c, "S3")

decomp_combn %>% 
  map(~select(df_out, .)) %>%
  set_names(map(., ~str_c(names(.), collapse = "_"))) %>% 
  map(~apply(., 1, sum)) %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  bind_cols(df_out, .)
```

Comment: Can you make the numbers more intuitive so that when the number of decompositions (Ds) increases the code works fine?

Comment: Thanks for your code. It is working fine but giving only `D1+S3 D2+S3 D3+S3`. `D1+D2+S3 D1+D3+S3` combinations are not coming.

Comment: I forgot to include `D1+D2+S3` and `D1+D3+S3`, but I've edited the post to include them, but adapting it to a variable number of decompositions is going to be a bit more complicated

Comment: Now it's perfectly fine. Can we add/retain every original series also in the data frame?

Comment: I've changed the original code to retain the original variables. Also, I have added code for a variable number of decompositions.

Comment: Now it is giving all possible combinations only for the first decomposition. Other decompositions are missing.

Comment: The code on the bottom doesn't output a data frame with 12 columns for you?

Comment: Thank you very very much. The second chunk is coming below the first one. Solved my problem. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

A little late - but here is a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
          D1 = c(-0.253, 0.253, -0.951, 0.951, 0.501, -0.501),
          D2 = c(-0.52, -0.52, 0.52, 0.52, -0.172, -0.172),
          D3 = c(0.014, 0.014, 0.014, 0.014, -0.014, -0.014),
          S3 = c(0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095),
          D1 = c(-0.966, 0.966, -0.647, 0.647, 0.905, -0.905),
          D2 = c(-0.078, -0.078, 0.078, 0.078, -0.943, -0.943),
          D3 = c(-0.046, -0.046, -0.046, -0.046, 0.046, 0.046),
          S3 = c(0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07)
)

DT[, c("D1+S3", "D2+S3", "D3+S3", "D1+D2+S3", "D1+D3+S3") := list(D1+S3, D2+S3, D3+S3, D1+D2+S3, D1+D3+S3)]

DT
```

---

```
       D1     D2     D3    S3     D1     D2     D3   S3  D1+S3  D2+S3 D3+S3 D1+D2+S3 D1+D3+S3
1: -0.253 -0.520  0.014 0.095 -0.966 -0.078 -0.046 0.07 -0.158 -0.425 0.109   -0.678   -0.144
2:  0.253 -0.520  0.014 0.095  0.966 -0.078 -0.046 0.07  0.348 -0.425 0.109   -0.172    0.362
3: -0.951  0.520  0.014 0.095 -0.647  0.078 -0.046 0.07 -0.856  0.615 0.109   -0.336   -0.842
4:  0.951  0.520  0.014 0.095  0.647  0.078 -0.046 0.07  1.046  0.615 0.109    1.566    1.060
5:  0.501 -0.172 -0.014 0.095  0.905 -0.943  0.046 0.07  0.596 -0.077 0.081    0.424    0.582
6: -0.501 -0.172 -0.014 0.095 -0.905 -0.943  0.046 0.07 -0.406 -0.077 0.081   -0.578   -0.420
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the current code you are providing the combinations manually. But in the original dataset many columns are there and for representation I have provided a small part of the data. So, it would be better if it can be made dynamically. You can see the comments of the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok, just a side question: D1, D2, D3, S3 are twice in your dataset. Are these two separate tables?

Comment: I have many columns and I have decomposed every column into Ds and Ss.

Comment: So it's intentional that you have duplicated column names?

Comment: Yes, it is like that only, though it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Quite long but should work:

```
data<-read.csv("Decompositions_1.csv")
nc_input=ncol(data)
nc_output = (ncol(data)/4)*5
output <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=nc_output,nrow=nrow(data))))
firsts=data[,seq(1,nc_input,4)]
seconds=data[,seq(2,nc_input,4)]
thirds=data[,seq(3,nc_input,4)]
fourths=data[,seq(4,nc_input,4)]
starts_ou=seq(1,nc_output,5)
subsets=1:length(starts_ou)
for(i in subsets) {
ou_index=starts_ou[i]
output[,ou_index]=firsts[i]+fourths[i]
output[,ou_index+1]=seconds[i]+fourths[i]
output[,ou_index+2]=thirds[i]+fourths[i]
output[,ou_index+3]=firsts[i]+thirds[i]+fourths[i]
output[,ou_index+4]=seconds[i]+thirds[i]+fourths[i]
}
```